# Android AudioTrack.write() returns -38

Tags: android, audiotrack

```
    int bufSizeMin = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
                                            44100,
                                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                            44100,
                                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                            bufSizeMin,
                                            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


    short[] audioData =  new short[2000];
    int writecount = audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
```

**sometime it returns 2000 (length of audiodata) and sometimes -38.**
**it should return 0 or positive values or -1 -2 or -3 if error generated. But what is -38? Please help..**

Comment: can you show the error stacktrace?

Comment: do you ever call `play()`? are you calling `write()` multiple times? we could help more if we knew more about the execution

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  1. there are no ERROR thrown. So No stacktrace.

Comment: @nandsito   2.`if(audioTrack.getPlayState() != AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING)audioTrack.play();`

Comment: but does it work if -38 is returned?

Comment: No. When it returns-38 nothing happens, audioteack playing nothing

Comment: I need to recreate the audiotrack instance to work it properly. It normally happens when new track started.